# Require SSH key + Google Authenticator for one account, SSH key only for another

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, google-authenticator

I am trying to setup an SSH authentication structure, but I'm struggling with issues in /etc/ssh/sshd_config vs /etc/pam.d/sshd.

### Requirements:

1. Accounts with root/sudo privileges

   - require public key authentication, followed immediately by
   - Google Authenticator
2. Unprivileged accounts

   - require only public key authentication

In other words, password based authentication should not be allowed, and public key authentication is always required, with Google Authenticator being conditionally required

### What is working:

Privileged accounts work exactly as I need: public key followed by Google Authenticator. I also verified that public keys missing from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys are rejected, and verified that login attempts without supplying any key are rejected.

### What is not working:

Unprivileged accounts seem to correctly prompt for the password to unlock the private key, and I think the key succeeds. But authentication fails with the message:

```
Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
```

```
$ ssh -v -i id_rsa_unprivileged unprivileged@blahblah
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 2071
Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa_unprvileged': 
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
unprivileged@blahblah: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
```

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/auth.log
Sep  3 00:44:13 hostname sshd[4249]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "user ingroup 2faexempt" was met by user "unprivileged"
Sep  3 00:44:13 hostname sshd[4247]: error: PAM: Permission denied for unprivileged from IP ADDRESS
Sep  3 00:44:13 hostname sshd[4247]: Connection closed by IP ADDRESS port PORT [preauth]
```

Note: Unprivileged accounts are correctly rejecting public keys missing from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, and are rejecting login attempts that don't supply a key.

### What I did:

My [strategy](https://askubuntu.com/a/864991/614210) was to create a group called "2faexempt", and add those accounts which should be exempted from 2 factor authentication (the unprivileged accounts). Then I edited /etc/ssh/sshd and /etc/pam.d/sshd to reflect the policy I need.

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22
AddressFamily inet
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

# USER ADDED
#
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# USER COMMENTED
# 
## Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password

# USER ADDED
#
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup 2faexempt
auth sufficient pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a way to make it work. It seems extremely hacky, but it works.

It doesn't seem safe to me.

```
$ cat relevant section of /etc/pam.d/sshd
...
# USER COMMENTED
# 
## Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth
...
# USER ADDED
#
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup 2faexempt
auth requisite pam_google_authenticator.so
auth required pam_permit.so
```